# How to sort array of dictionary with timestamp key in swift3?

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have created a merged array. Inside this array I have different dictionaries.I want to sort these dictionaries according to the timestamp key. I have used one method but its not working.

**Here is the structure of my merged array:**

```
`mergedArray------> (

        (

            {

        "delete_or_keep_member" = 1;

        "image_url" = advhgwqvhdq;

        "member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        message = "Hyy wants to transfer the medical records of Nikita Sarkar. Do you accept?";

        mid = X6OC;

        mobile = "+919571625612";

        name = Hyy;

        "receiver_member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        "sender_member_id" = "6242d4ec-f181-4d3d-a5de-cc138022f2c0";

        "time_stamp" = 1510740044283;

        title = "Record Transfer Request";

        type = "transfer_record_request";

        "type_code" = 102;

    },

            {

        "delete_or_keep_member" = 1;

        "image_url" = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/medata-development/X6OC/profile/image_3.jpg";

        "member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        message = "Nikita Sarkar wants to transfer the medical records of Nikita Sarkar. Do you accept?";

        mid = X6OC;

        mobile = "+919571625612";

        name = "Nikita Sarkar";

        "receiver_member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        "sender_member_id" = "fde7ad1d-c37d-4d5c-8b04-e81b3d39eaad";

        "time_stamp" = 1510746177;

        title = "Record Transfer Request";

        type = "transfer_record_request";

        "type_code" = 102;

    }

),

    (

            {

        attachments =             (

        );

        condition = Zbzbbz;

        "created_on_date_time" = "21/11/2017, 10:53 AM";

        doctor = "";

        "follow_up_appointments" =             (

        );

        hospital = "";

        id = "faf67a06-81ef-41ed-a4e3-d65d656389bc";

        "image_url" = 0;

        "member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        mid = X6OC;

        mobile = "+919571625612";

        note = "";

        place = "";

        "prescription_date" = "";

        "shared_members" =             (

        );

        symptoms = " Zz. ";

        "time_stamp" = 1511241790335;

        type = record;

        "type_code" = 101;

        "user_name" = You;

    },

            {

        attachments =             (

        );

        condition = Ghh;

        "created_on_date_time" = "20/11/2017, 6:25 PM";

        doctor = "";

        "follow_up_appointments" =             (

                            {

                "add_to_calendar" = no;

                "followup_id" = 0;

                notes = "";

                "remind_on_date" = "20/11/2017";

                "remind_on_time" = "08 : 29 PM";

                "remind_type" = null;

                "time_stamp" = 1511189973015000;

            },

                            {

                "add_to_calendar" = no;

                "followup_id" = 1;

                notes = "";

                "remind_on_date" = "25/11/2017";

                "remind_on_time" = "10 : 43 AM";

                "remind_type" = null;

                "time_stamp" = 1511586813018000;

            },

                            {

                "add_to_calendar" = no;

                "followup_id" = 2;

                notes = "";

                "remind_on_date" = "21/11/2017";

                "remind_on_time" = "10 : 46 AM";

                "remind_type" = sound;

                "time_stamp" = 1511241393021000;

            }

        );

        hospital = "";

        id = "0f6ec05d-d223-4ffe-a5c1-a1e597e4683e";

        "image_url" = 0;

        "member_id" = "fd65e27c-2d2f-47e5-ac93-1a02cf4fda2c";

        mid = X6OC;

        mobile = "+919571625612";

        note = "";

        place = "";

        "prescription_date" = "21/11/2017";

        "shared_members" =             (

        );

        symptoms = "";

        "time_stamp" = 1511182516234;

        type = record;

        "type_code" = 101;

        "updated_on_date_time" = "21/11/2017 5:14 AM";

        "user_name" = You;

        }

    )

)`
```

**Below is my Code:**

```
self.newsortedArray = self.newsortedArray.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "time_stamp", ascending: true)])
```

After implementing this method got this error below

> -[__NSArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c043cfa0 2017-11-22 18:34:31.322043+0530 Medata[3821:1826841] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI compare:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c043cfa0'

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: Rather than an **array of dictionaries** the object is an **array of arrays of dictionaries**.  What is the expected result?

Comment: i have corrected my merged array.It is now array of dictionary only. but when i sort this  merged array its not working .

Comment: It seems that the array is Foundation `NSArray`. Don't use that. Cast the array to a Swift native type.

Answer (score 0):

As Vadian said you have an array of arrays of dictionaries so to sort it you can try:

```
self.newsortedArray = self.newsortedArray.map { 
    $0.sorted { ($0["test"] as! Int) < ($1["test"]! as! Int) } }
```

**Edit:**

If you now have an array of dictionaries you can use this, if your array is AnyObject type’s you have to cast it before applying sorted:

```
self.newsortedArray = (self.newsortedArray as! [[String: Any]]).sorted { ($0["test"] as! Int) < ($1["test"]! as! Int) } }
```

Comment: Thank you @vadian!

Comment: I got this error after adding this code "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'sorted'"

Comment: it says " Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Comment: Please do not use Foundation `NSArray`. You are fighting the strong type system.

Comment: my  newsortedArray is NSMutable type

Comment: `NSMutable...` collection types are still worse. Never use those. Once again use a Swift native type, the `var` keyword makes it mutable.